# Having my Python package install shortcuts in Start menu

Tags: python, installation, setuptools

I'm making a Python package that gets installed with a `setup.py` file using setuptools.

The package includes a GUI, and when it's installed on a Windows machine, I want the installation to make a folder in "Programs" in the start menu, and make a shortcut there to a `pyw` script that will start the GUI. (The `pyw` think works on all platforms, right?)

On Mac and Linux, I would like it to put this shortcut in whatever Mac and Linux have that is parallel to the start menu.

How do I do this?

Comment: Incidentally, Mac OS X doesn't really have a Start menu analog. You could package your program as a Mac app using p2app (and optionally install it in `/Application`): http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html

Comment: Regarding your `pyw` question, yes, it's cross-platform.

Comment: @mipadi: It's too early in my program's development to use a bundled-installer such as py2app. I will sure use it at a later phase. I was hoping for a cross-platform thing now.

Answer (score 2):

Linux systems typically do not use a .pyw extension for executable applications (though you could if you wish). Traditionally, a python (or perl, bash, etc) script on Linux has no file name extension, has execution permissions, and begins with the 'magic' line "#!/usr/bin/python'. The '#!' lets the OS know that this is a script requiring an interpreter and the following path denotes the interpreter to use.

As for adding the desktop shortcut, [freedesktop.org](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications) hosts the specifications for how menus work for modern Linux desktops. Specifically, the one you'll be most interested in is the one for [Desktop Entries](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.0.html) though the one on [Menu Generation](http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-1.0.html) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

[InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) allows you to create shorcuts in the windows start menu. You can add even an uninstall icon.

The relevant sections of the innosetup file are:

```
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\myico.ico
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\MyPrograms"; Filename: "{app}\miexe.exe" ;WorkingDir: "{app}"; Comment: "miexe program"
```

for Mac and Linux I can not help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how the [post-install script](http://pywin32.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pywin32/pywin32/pywin32_postinstall.py?revision=1.32&view=markup) for pywin32 does it (search for shortcut).  Not sure about Mac/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Since setuptools doesn't seem to give an easy solution to this, I've decided to give up on this idea until I release my app with py2exe/InnoSetup.

Answer (score 0):

For windows, conda uses `menuinst` https://github.com/ContinuumIO/menuinst